# JQueryMobile Login Page Redirect on Successful Login

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-mobile

Trying to redirect a user to index.php after they login successfully.  I have everything working except the redirect.  Been looking around for about an hour now and no luck..I'm sure it is tied to jQueryMobile owning the page

Have tried

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

nothing happens.

Also tried

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">$.mobile.changePage($(\'index.php\'), {transition : "slide"});</script>';
```

Both do a re-direct if I make them the first part of my php code, but when placed where I need it they do nothing.

Here is my code:

```
<?php include "layouts/header.php"; 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Form has been submitted.

  $username = trim($_POST['username']);
  $password = trim($_POST['password']);

  // Check database to see if username/password exist.
    $hashpass = sha1($password);
    $found_user = User::authenticate($username, $hashpass);

  if ($found_user) {
    $session->login($found_user);
    $message = "Logged in";
    // Redirect to index.php ********

  } else {
    // username/password combo not found 
    $message = "Username/password combination incorrect.";
    $forgotdisplay = "visible";
  }

} else { // Form was not been submitted.
  $username = "";
  $password = "";
}
?>
</head>
<body>
 <div data-role="page" id="loginForm">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Assessment</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" class="centerContent">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <p><?php echo output_message($message); ?></p>
        <form action="login.php" method="post" data-ajax="false">
          <table>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" maxlength="50" placeholder="username" value="<?php echo htmlentities($username); ?>" />
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" maxlength="30" placeholder="password" value="<?php echo htmlentities($password); ?>" />            
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />       
        </form>
        <a href="register.php" data-role="button" data-transition="slide">Sign Up</a>
        <a href="forgot.php" data-role="button">Forgot Your Password?</a>
        <p id="validate-status"></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When valid credentials are submitted the `$message` does correctly change to "Logged in" so I know that I am getting that far in the script.  Have also tried with `data-ajax="false"` and `"true"`

Answer (score 0):

Hello you may want to put the full domain in there. I had this problem too

```
header('location: www.yourdomain.com/index.php');
```

I believe that should do the trick

Comment: yup, tried that as well. nothing happens.  I added $message = "Did not redirect" after the redirect line and that message displayed.  It's like any attempt to redirect the page is ignored.